# static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression with __builtin_clz

Tags: c++, clang

I have the following code:

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;

constexpr int leaing_ones(uchar const u8) noexcept {
  return __builtin_clz(static_cast<uchar>(~static_cast<unsigned>(u8))) +
         sizeof(uchar) * 8 - sizeof(int) * 8;
}

int main() {
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b0000'0000) == 0);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1000'0000) == 1);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1100'0000) == 2);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1110'0000) == 3);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'0000) == 4);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1000) == 5);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1000) == 5);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1100) == 6);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1110) == 7);
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1111) == 8);
}
```

I [tested](https://godbolt.org/z/6qGr8ojo9) these with clang 12 and GCC 11.1. The only problem is that clang specifically doesn't like the last assertation:

```
<source>:16:17: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
  static_assert(leaing_ones(0b1111'1111) == 8);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As far as I can tell, I am not causing any kind of overflow, and GCC works fine with all of them. Is this a clang bug, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: By the way in C++ 20, there is `std::countl_one`

Comment: @harold amazing. It [seems to](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sG83sW75x) not work for `char8_t` from C++20 though. Any idea why? I'll just cast `char8_t` to `unsigned char` before calling `std::countl_one`. Thank you!

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Most stuff involving bit patterns is weird if you allow for negative numbers to get involved (not as much as it used to be now that two's complement is mandatory, but people get stuck in their ways).

Comment: @harold `char8_t` is unsigned

Comment: Huh, scratch that, `char8_t` is defined to match the signedness (along with size and alignment) of `unsigned char`. It's a distinct type though, so it's possible the compiler refuses to promote it? Weird. Edit: Heh, typing at the same time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger all character types (except for signed char and sometimes plain char) are unsigned.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: Yeah, initially I thought it was like `char` (implementation-defined signedness, which is terrible), but I was checking myself.

Comment: cppreference says "This overload participates in overload resolution only if T is an unsigned integer type (that is, unsigned char, unsigned short, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long long, or an extended unsigned integer type)." I don't know why they excluded char types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__builtin_clz` is undefined for an argument with value zero](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), and since you invert all the bits, `0b1111'1111` becomes the pattern of all zeroes. Your function will need to special case `0` to use an appropriate value.

Comment: Well, why is GCC fine with it then? I thought all UB must be reported in constant expressions.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: I can't say why GCC allows it; undefined behavior need not be reported, but it stops it from being a core constant expression. See #7 on [cppreference's core constant exclusions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression): "an expression whose evaluation leads to any form of core language undefined behavior (including signed integer overflow, division by zero, pointer arithmetic outside array bounds, etc). Whether standard library undefined behavior is detected is unspecified." So this should break the `static_assert` (not being static officially).

Comment: Unless someone can show otherwise, I'd mark it down as a minor defect (GCC doesn't realize undefined behavior is involved).

Answer (score 1):

Passing `0` to `__builtin_clz` is undefined behavior.

From [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit position. **If x is 0, the result is undefined.**

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

Comment: Well, why is GCC fine with it then? I thought all UB must be reported in constant expressions.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Well, it's not a "true" UB, since it's not the standard that says it's undefined. But I concur with ShadowRanger that it looks like a tiny GCC bug.